# Use a graph to estimate the time at which the number was increasing most rapidly

Tags: functions, derivatives, logarithms, graphing-functions

For the period from 2000 to 2008, the percentage of households in a certain country with at least one DVD player has been modeled by the function

$f(t) = \frac{87.5}{1 + 17.1e^{−0.91t}}$

where the time $t$ is measured in years since midyear 2000, so $0 \leq t \leq 8$.
 Use a graph to estimate the time at which the number of households with DVD players was increasing most rapidly. Then use derivatives to give a more accurate estimate. (Round your answer to two decimal places.)
$t = ?$

Comment: Say what you have tried so far so that we can help you better.

Comment: I think I need to find the inflection point. So, first I found derivative which is -(1361.5875e^(-0.91t))/(1+17.1e^(-0.91t))^2; Then, I tried to find second derivative but it is so complicated and now I am not sure that I am doing its right...

Comment: I don't think this problem is in any way life-threatening. So please remove the misplace cry of alarm from your title.

Comment: I need to solve this problem till 11pm,cause I have a deadline in online assignment

Answer (score 1):

Because you are asked to use a graph you should start by plotting $f(t)$ in mathematica, matlab, maple etc. If you don't have access to any of this software take a look at wolframalpha. Then, the time it is increasing most rapidly should be where the slope is greatest. You are right, you will need to find an inflection point which is the deravitave of the slope, or the second derivative of the function and find the critical values, i.e. set it equal to zero and solve for $t$. And you are right, it might get ugly, but it will reduce.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have 
$$\begin{align}
f'(t)&=87.5\cdot\frac{17.1\cdot -.91e^{-.91t}}{1+17.1e^{-.91t}} \\
&=87.5\cdot\frac{17.1\cdot -.91e^{-.91t}-.91+.91}{1+17.1e^{-.91t}} \\
&=87.5\cdot.91\left(\frac{1}{1+17.1e^{-.91t}}-1\right) \\
&=87.5\cdot.91(f(t)-1)
\end{align}$$

That should make it easier to solve for $f''(t)$, and hence $f''(t)=0$.  You can take it from here.